# Listview Row incrementing with new value

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview with radio buttons now i need to add one value from a edittext after typing some thing in the edittext the typed text should appear in the listview as next row.? how it is posible.?

Answer (score 0):

**ListView with simpleArrayAdapter  :**

Follow these steps it may help:

```
  1. Fetch the value from edit text after the user types using gettext()
  2. Insert this value in an array.
  3. create a list view.
  4. create an arrayAdapter with the already created array as source.
  5. Now set the adapter with listview using (array variable).setAdapter(adapter name);
```

For every time the user updates use `notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh your listview with the new contents.

Pseudo code:

```
 onClick(){
       array.add(editText.gettext());
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
```

[Click here for more.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)